# Adding "hold on" after "figure" causes the plot to be different

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I've three `5x5` matrices, i.e. `X`, `Y` and `U`. Here's how they look like.

```
X =

         0         0         0         0         0
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.7500    0.7500    0.7500    0.7500    0.7500
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000


Y =

         0    0.2500    0.5000    0.7500    1.0000
         0    0.2500    0.5000    0.7500    1.0000
         0    0.2500    0.5000    0.7500    1.0000
         0    0.2500    0.5000    0.7500    1.0000
         0    0.2500    0.5000    0.7500    1.0000


U =

         0    0.2474    0.4794    0.6816    0.8415
    0.3093    0.5991    0.8519    1.0519    1.1862
    0.7191    1.0224    1.2623    1.4238    1.4962
    1.1929    1.4727    1.6611    1.7460    1.7220
    1.6829    1.8980    1.9950    1.9680    1.8186
```

Now if I try to plot `U` using the following snippet:

```
figure;
mesh(X, Y, U);
```

This is the output:

[image]

If instead I use the following code:

```
figure;
hold on;
mesh(X, Y, U);
```

I get:

[image]

Why is this happening? Apparently without `hold on` I've one more dimension. I don't know for my case which one would be correct. Why does Matlab does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand what is happening, it's important to know that for most MATLAB plotting commands, if no `axes` is explicitly supplied to the command, the current `axes` is used by default. If no `axes` exists, one is created and it's appearance is controlled completely by the plotting command. If there *is* a current `axes` object, typically the plot command will *not* modify the appearance of the `axes` object since in theory you have already customized it.

`hold on` modifies the `NexPlot` property of the current axes so that the next object that's plotted won't overwrite previous objects. If no `axes` currently exists, `hold` will implicitly create an `axes` object. The default view of this new axes object is a 2D XY view. Since an `axes` object now already exists when you call `mesh`, it just uses the current view (and other `axes` parameters) rather than altering it.

In the case where you don't call `hold on`, no `axes` is present before calling `mesh`, so `mesh` creates a default `axes` object itself with properties that are ideal for visualizing a mesh. This includes using a 3D view and displaying grid lines.

You can manually change the properties of the `axes` created by `hold on` by calling `view(3)` to use the default 3D view and `grid on` to turn on the grid marks

```
figure
hold on

% Make it the default 3D view
view(3)

% Show the gridlines
grid on

mesh(X, Y, U)
```

Comment: To extend this slightly, `hold` modifies the `axes` object's [`NextPlot` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_NextPlot). When you set `hold on`, `NextPlot` is set to `'add'`, which adds the plot to the existing axes without resetting or modifying the axes properties (e.g. changing the view from 2D to 3D).